# This program is written in C and I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. Trying to print 'meow' 3 times

Tags: c

Mentioned below is a code written in C. I'm trying to print out 'meow' three times using a for loop by giving it an input of (3) but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Could someone please help explain where I've gone wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Prototype
void meow (void);

int main (void)
{
    meow(3);
}

void meow(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("meow\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for compiler warnings: they matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the prototype at the top to

> void meow (int n);

A function prototype is a very important feature of C. It provides a function definition for the code which instructs the compiler about the parameters and return types of the function. Right now you have it defined as taking in void, however you want to pass in an integer.

Since you are passing in an integer to your function you need to specify that is what you want the function to take in so the compiler knows what to expect.

Comment: This answer could definitely use more clarification on how and why this fixes the problem.

Comment: @ChrisDutton you are correct, my apologies

Comment: No problem. There isn't a single one of us who can't improve.

Comment: That worked. thanks a lot for that and the explanation too.